# views_query_alter apply "%LIKE%" condition

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way in which I can alter the view query so I can get items that contain a specified string in title?

For example something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['query']) && (!empty($_GET['query']))) {
    $view->query->add_where('title', $_GET['query'], 'LIKE');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if (!empty($_GET['query'])) {
    $query->add_where(0, 'title', $_GET['query'], 'LIKE');
  }
}
```

The first argument that is required from [$query->add_where()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3a%3aadd_where/7) is the group for the WHERE to add. The documentation says to pass 0 as argument, to use the default one.

The code I shown works if `$_GET['query']` contains an SQL regular expression. If `$_GET['query']` contains a string that is not a regular expression, and that is used to build the regular expression for example as `'%' . $_GET['query'] . '%'`, the code to use should be the following one.

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if (!empty($_GET['query'])) {
    $query->add_where(0, 'title', '%' . db_like($_GET['query']) . '%', 'LIKE');
  }
}
```

Notice what reported in the documentation for `views_plugin_query_default::add_where()`:

> The caller is responsible for ensuring that all fields are fully qualified (TABLE.FIELD) and that the table already exists in the query.

#### References

- [hook_views_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)
- [The list of functions/methods invoking `hook_views_query_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/invokes/hook_views_query_alter/7)
- [db_like()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_like/7)